# Using Arrhenius equation to calculate the ratio of two reaction rates

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

> For two reactions,
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \ce{A ->[$k_1$] B} \tag{1} \\
> \ce{A ->[$k_2$] C} \tag{2}
> \end{align}$$
>
> you have determined that the activation energies are $\pu{71.9 kJ/mol}$ for $(1)$ and $\pu{142.8 kJ/mol}$ for $(2)$. If the *rate constants* are equal at a temperature of $\pu{321 K}$, at what temperature will $k_1/k_2$ be equal to $2$?

I know I have to use the Arrhenius equation

$$k=A\exp\left(-\frac{E_\mathrm A}{RT}\right),$$

and I've tried solving for $T$ after filling in my data into the formula as ratios, ie $k_1/k_2$, $E_\mathrm{A}^{(1)}/E_\mathrm{A}^{(2)}$, etc, but I can't seem to get a coherent answer. Any guidance on figuring this out would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

To a first approximation, the activation energy of a single given reaction is a constant at all temperatures (see reasons [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_energy#Temperature_independence_and_the_relation_to_the_Arrhenius_equation), although more precisely, there is some temperature variation). However, the activation energies for *both* reactions need not be the same.

If you consider both reactions at $\pu{321 K}$,

$$\begin{align}
\ln k_1 &= \ln k_2 \tag{1}\\
\ln A_1 - \frac{E_{\mathrm A}^{(1)}}{(\pu{321 K})R} &= \ln A_2 - \frac{E_\mathrm{A}^{(2)}}{(\pu{321 K})R} \tag{2}\\[4pt]
\ln A_1 - \ln A_2 &= \frac{E_{\mathrm A}^{(1)} - E_{\mathrm A}^{(2)}}{(\pu{321 K})R} \tag{3} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{\pu{71.9 kJ mol-1} - \pu{142.8 kJ mol-1}}{(\pu{321 K})(\pu{8.31446 J K-1 mol-1})} \tag{3} \\[4pt]
&= -26.56 \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

Now, denote the desired temperature at which $k_1  = 2k_2$ as $T^*$. At this new temperature, we have

$$\begin{align}
\ln k_1 &= \ln 2 + \ln k_2 \tag{5}\\
\ln A_1 - \frac{E_{\mathrm A}^{(1)}}{T^*R} &= \ln 2 + \ln A_2 - \frac{E_\mathrm{A}^{(2)}}{T^*R} \tag{6}\\[4pt]
\ln A_1 - \ln A_2 - \ln 2 &= \frac{E_{\mathrm A}^{(1)} - E_{\mathrm A}^{(2)}}{T^*R} \tag{7}
\end{align}$$

Here we can reuse the previously calculated value for $\ln A_1 - \ln A_2$, and we can also plug in the same activation energies:

$$\begin{align}
T^* &= \frac{E_{\mathrm A}^{(1)} - E_{\mathrm A}^{(2)}}{R(\ln A_1 - \ln A_2 - \ln 2)} \tag{8} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{\pu{71.9 kJ mol-1} - \pu{142.8 kJ mol-1}}{(\pu{8.31446 J K-1 mol-1})(-26.56 - 0.693)} \tag{9} \\[4pt]
&= \pu{313 K}. \tag{10}
\end{align}$$